# Layouts slots in Blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

There is the pre-defined slot `@Body` in Blazor, but what about custom slots?
Could they be defined?
In below example, such slots are `@AdditionalUpperFixedContent`, `@AdditionalSidebarContent`, `@AdditionalFloatingContent`.

```xml
<div class="MainLayout">
  
  <div class="MainLayout-UpperFixedContentSlot">
    <Header hamburgerMenuButtonAdditionalCSS_Class="MainLayout-HamburgerMenuButton" />
    @AdditionalUpperFixedContent
  </div>
  
  <div class="MainLayout-Sidebar">
    <NavigationMenu />
    @AdditionalSidebarContent
  </div>
  
  <main class="MainLayout-SpecificContent">
    @Body
  </main>

  <Snackbar/>  
  <BlockingLoadingOverlay/>
  @AdditionalFloatingContent
  
</div>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Can you give an example of how these slots will be populated?

Comment: Google ".net 8 Blazor Sections"-- I think this might be what you're looking for.  --edit-- here maybe this? https://www.telerik.com/blogs/aspnet-8-blazor-sections-fully-explained

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Looks like... I'll check once update to .net 8. Thank you for the recommendation.